# How to config Font substitution in poppler

Tags: poppler, fontconfig, poppler-utils

When convert pdf page to image, if a Font is not embedded in the input pdf, default Font substitution (usually Arial) is used. However, I want to change the default font.

There is a [description here](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/poppler/) but it is too few information. I don't know how to create and where to put the config file.

OS: Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 3):

The page you mentioned saved me, thanks!
Here is how:

As they indicate, what is needed is to configure `fontconfig`. I can't be sure for Ubuntu, but for Debian this means creating or editing this file :

/etc/fonts/local.conf

For the font substitution, you just need to include something like this example:

```
<alias>
    <family>Helvetica</family>
    <accept><family>Nimbus Sans L</family></accept>
</alias>
```

Where the Helvetica family would be substituted by the 'Nimbus Sans L' family.

To check that it works, you may use a PDF file containing e.g. Helvetica, and type:

pdffonts -subst <yourfile>.pdf

This will list the fonts substitutions. In my case, it worked just fine, with poppler now doing the right substitution.

Answer (score 1):

For Fedora, I created `~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf` with following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
<match target="pattern">
 <test name="family">
  <string>Helvetica</string>
 </test>
 <edit name="family" mode="prepend" binding="strong">
  <string>Liberation Sans</string>
 </edit>
</match>
</fontconfig>
```

It worked fine, tested with `fc-match Helvetica` and `pdffonts -subst <yourfile>.pdf`

I recommend the arch linux wiki for more [font configuration info](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/font_configuration).